# How do I make a generic delegate using a type in C#?

Tags: c#, types, delegates, unity-game-engine

If I have a type, like:

```
Type type = myObject.GetType ();
```

How do I make a generic delegate that uses objects of that that type as a parameter? I would expect code something like:

```
myDelegate = Action<type> (type parameter);
```

The above code obviously won't and doesn't work as is, but how can I make it work? Can I even make it work?

Ultimately, I have a dictionary of Dictionary < Type, List < Action < > >, which holds a type and a list of delegates that should take an object of that type as parameter.

And should be executed something like this:

```
myDict[myType][i] (objectOfMyType);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Generics shouldn't need to know what type they are working with. This is what makes them *generic*.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773099/generating-delegate-types-dynamically-in-c-sharp

Comment: a real-world example would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might expect, you can't use instantiations of the `Action<>` type directly in the dictionary. You'll have to type it to `System.Delegate`, and use `DynamicInvoke`:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>> dict;

dict[myType][i].DynamicInvoke(objectOfMyType);
```

and to create the delegates in the first place, use reflection:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(myType);

MethodInfo delegatedMethod = typeof(ContainingType).GetMethod("MethodToInvoke");

Delegate myDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, delegatedMethod);
dict.Add(myType, new List<Delegate> {myDelegate});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well! I only used the top block of code and that got me on the right path, bye-bye boilerplate casts!