# Pass a Func<T,bool> as a parameter using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a method:

```
public bool DoStuff<T>(T obj) {
  // Do Stuff
  return result;
}
```

And I need to pass that as a Func<T, bool> parameter to another method that I don't know at compile time.  Let's say that method looks like:

```
public int Any(Func<int, bool> arg) {
}
```

Or

```
public int Any(Func<string, bool> arg) {
}
```

So I'm invoking that method like this:

```
return instance.GetType().InvokeMember(method.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, args);
```

What I can't figure out is how to wrap up a reference to DoStuff as a Func<T,bool>, where I don't know T at compile time, but DO know it at runtime, and stuff it into an object[] to provide as the parameters to the method call.

If it helps, I'm writing an interpreter of a simple language.  DoStuff will interpret a lambda expression in the simple language and the invoked methods will be .NET functions provided by the consumer of the interpreter.

**Update**

After following the link provided in the comments by Hans (thanks!) I've implemented the following:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new []{argType, typeof(bool)});
MethodInfo delegatedMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(DoStuff), BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
MethodInfo generic = delegatedMethod.MakeGenericMethod(argType);

Delegate myDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, generic);
var args = new object[] { myDelegate };

return instance.GetType().InvokeMember(method.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, args);
```

But the InvokeMember call gives me *System.MissingMethodException: 'Method 'MyDomain.Any' not found.'*

When I inspect the **myDelegate** variable in Visual Studio it shows:

```
myDelegate = {Method = {Boolean DoStuff[Func`2](System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean])}
```

It's the ONLY element in the **args** array, and the method signature I'm invoking is:

```
public int Any(Func<int, bool> arg)
```

**instance** is an instance of the class containing the Any method, and **method** is a MethodInfo for the Any method.

Comment: Well, that's not what generics are designed for. I guess, you might want to look for a solution using [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933565/how-do-i-make-a-generic-delegate-using-a-type-in-c

Comment: @littlecharva could you verify that https://pastebin.com/3UxN6Sn4  is a viable example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Lause Yes, that's it.  I created a new project and pasted in your code, which works perfectly.  I then started replacing your code with my code and discovered the problem: in my code I was passing Func<int,bool> as the argType, when I should have been passing int.  It now works perfectly!  Do you want to post a link to your pastebin as the answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks so much for helping me find my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's some code that works:

```
public class AnyImplementer
{
   public int Any(Func<int, bool> func)
    {
        return func(10)? 1: 0;
    }

  
}

public class DoStuffer
{
    public bool DoStuff<T>(T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString() != string.Empty;
    }

    public int a(Type argType, AnyImplementer anyImplementer)
    {
        Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] { argType, typeof(bool) });
        MethodInfo delegatedMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(DoStuff), BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        MethodInfo generic = delegatedMethod.MakeGenericMethod(argType);

        Delegate myDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, generic);
        var args = new object[] { myDelegate };

        return (int)anyImplementer.GetType().InvokeMember("Any", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, anyImplementer, args);
    }
}


public class Program
{
   
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoStuffer DoStuffer = new DoStuffer();
        AnyImplementer anyImplementer = new AnyImplementer();
       Console.WriteLine(DoStuffer.a(typeof(int), anyImplementer));
       
    }

    
}
```

Also accessible at
https://pastebin.com/raw/3UxN6Sn4 -
The idea is (as based on OP's updates and related questions) to create wrap the method instance into an object using a delegate constructed out of the method info of the generic method group.