# Dynamic delegate type parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

In C# can you do something like

```
Func<typeof(variableType),int)> myDelegate;
```

where you can pass the type arguments dynamically to a delegate?

Comment: The closest you can get is `Func<object, int>` or just `delegate myDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. typeof() is evaluated at run-time. Your delegate declaration is evaluated at compile time. The typeof() evaluation would have to occur first for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `Func<typeof(variableType),int)> myDelegate;`.and get syntax error.

Use:

```
        Func<object,int> myDelegate;
```

or:

```
        Func<dynamic,int> myDelegate;
```

And see this:[Generating Delegate Types dynamically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773099/generating-delegate-types-dynamically-in-c-sharp?rq=1)