# Best way to cache a reflection property getter / setter?

Tags: c#, performance, caching, reflection, properties

I know that Reflection can be expensive. I have a class that gets/sets to properties often, and one way I figured was to cache the reflection somehow. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to cache an expression or what to do here really. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, value, null);
typeof(T).GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
```

So... what would be the best way to make this quicker?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should cache results of

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
```

and

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
```

Another possible approach is to combine [PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod.aspx)  (or [PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod.aspx)  for setter) with [Delegate.CreateDelegate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx)  and invoke the resulting delegate every time you need to get/set values. If you need this to work with generics you can use approach from this question: [CreateDelegate with unknown types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490828/createdelegate-with-unknown-types/2493903#2493903)

This should be much faster compared to reflection:
[Making reflection fly and exploring delegates](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/)

There are also other ways to get/set values in a faster way. You can use expression trees or DynamicMethod to generate the il at runtime. Have a look at these links:

[Late-Bound Invocations with DynamicMethod](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/08/06/late-bound-invocations-with-dynamicmethod/)

[Delegate.CreateDelegate vs DynamicMethod vs Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597819/delegate-createdelegate-vs-dynamicmethod-vs-expression)

Comment: +1, delegates are the way to go if you want the best performance

Comment: The delegates seems like the way to go, but that article is a bit over my head. Could you show an example pertaining to what I'd be using it for?

Comment: you say "you should cache results of X and Y", but X and Y are the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the simplest answer is that you could cache the `PropertyInfo` object returned by `GetProperty`:

```
var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
propInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

// etc.
```

That would eliminate the need for Reflection to repeatedly find the property in the class and eliminate the bulk of the performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

Marc Gravell has written a brilliant article about his [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx).
It should provide a much faster runtime reflective property access.

Answer (score 2):

Just store a reference to the `PropertyInfo` that is returned from:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(propName)
```